# Pass Checkbox checked value to Script Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a table with a checkbox column - when you click the checkbox it performs a script that includes an AJAX request. I'm trying to set the checked state into a variable so I can then include this as a parameter in the AJAX POST request but I'm not able to get this into a variable so far.

Here's my checkbox input field with the script that is simplified to just capture the checked state of the input in the `checkedState` variable:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input.select-item").click(function() {
    var productID = $(this).val();
    var checkedState = $("input.select-item").attr("checked");
    console.log(checkedState);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<td id="AT36288"><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="AT36288" /></td>
```

So if the checkbox was not checked and the user checks this I would like to capture the value of "checked" in the variable, and if the checkbox was checked and the user unchecked this I would like to capture the value of "uncheck" in the variable. I'm getting an `undefined` result for the variable in the console.

Comment: I just put the checkbox in the snippet and closed your DOM ready handler, and it seems to work just fine?

Comment: You have better to use `var checkedState = $("input.select-item").prop("checked");` or `var checkedState = $("input.select-item").is(":checked");`. And if you want to get `checked/uncheck` strings, you can use: `var checkedState = $("input.select-item").is(":checked") ? "checked" : "uncheck";` BUT passing boolean instead (`true or false`) seems more legit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st :** you need to use is checked `$(this).is(":checked")`

**2nd :** you need to use `$(this)` instead of `$("input.select-item").attr("checked")` because you need to refer the `currently clicked` element instead of `class name`  `$("input.select-item")`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input.select-item").click(function() {
    var productID = $(this).val();
    var checkedState = $(this).is(":checked");
    console.log(checkedState);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<td id="AT36288"><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="AT36288" /></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi the checkboxes and radioboxes events can be tracked better by change event.
In jQuery you can check the status of the input field by following:
$("input.select-item").is(":checked") or 
simply $(".select-item").is(":checked")
Hope this helps.